# multiple search within a cell and offset result if found

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet with column B:B displaying more than 30k entries.
I am trying to find a way to :
- check whether the each of these cells as content from range "content1"
- if so, then also check same cell if is also has content from range "content2" adjacent to first one (but range not necessarily same length than "content1" AND if possible at all, not necessarily either existing;
- and ideally with the possibility to add a couple of more ranges to search for...
IF content from range1 AND 2 [AND x] are found in a cell from column B:B, then fetch the content of a cell to the right of first cells showing "content1"..."content2"... and write it where formula is located...
Easier probably to show an exemple :

```
Colum B:B                      Range1    Range2   Range3  Rangexx  Result
The quick brown fox jumps      fox       brown     quick  jumps    Fast Animal               
The green tree moves slowly    tree      green     fast            Green Vegetal                                   
The brown tree moves slowly    tree      brown     slow            Brown Vegetal                                        
The green house in the tree    house     green                     House green                                                                                  
Hitchhiker guide to the galaxy galaxy    guide                     Space
```

Result would thus be :

```
Column B:B                           Column C:C
The quick brown fox jumps            Fast Animal
The green tree moves slowly          ""
The brown tree moves slowly          Brown Vegetal
The green house in the tree          House green                                              
Hitchhiker guide to the galaxy       Space
```

What i am trying to achieve is to categorize a large body of words using multiple criteria ...

I have found (and tested) a formula that allows me to test text from column B:B (using arrays) on ONE criteria and return a category - which is already awesome...

But was wondering whether you experts would be able to actually push this further and - using either VBA our excel formula - allow me to do this categorization using multiple criteria!

Formula is `=INDEX(result_text;MATCH(TRUE;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(search_text;B2));0))`

With `result_text` the offset categoory accessed is the search of `search_text` in B2 has been successful! :)

I have also found a VBA macro that doesn't seem too far from what I am trying to achieve, but my VBA skills are too limited yet to adapt it (search and looping seem there already) : [Search Multiple different string in excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371236/search-multiple-different-string-in-excel-vba) ...

Also, first time am posting here - so do tell me if I have done anything wrong in writing this post! :)

Txs!
M.

exemple
[link to exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxoF5.png)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OceFTFVz_-isGNkBXcKdIY4cxQ4vqKSf

Comment: I am not sure, but wouldn't =INDEX(result_text;MATCH(TRUE;AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(search_text1;B2);ISNUMBER(SEARCH(search_text2;B2)));0)) work?

Comment: txs for getting back to me!
let me try :)

Comment: OK - not working as your formula just takes the first element of each of the two ranges each time when it should cycle through each items in the range. I need the formula to look for each of the elements in turn, and retrieve the one that has the first 2 (or more if more) values in it...
   
List of expressions  Result   
tarif internat lycée thuillier amiens  internat lycéee   
tarif internat lycée vauban brest  internat lycéee   
tarif internat lycée voltaire orléans  internat lycéee   
tarifs internat  public  internat public   
trouver un internat  trouver  un internat

Comment: I have added an example to mt initial post to try n clarify what am trying to achieve... :)

Comment: I do not have access to excel at the moment to test anything, but something like this should be close to the correct solution: =INDEX(result_text;MATCH(1;SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(search_range1;B2);ISNUMBER(SEARCH(search_range2;B2)));0)). You might need to enter it as an array formula, not sure though.

Comment: tried your solution and getting an #/NA error when entering it in the cell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to loop through your constant range

```
dim cell as Range
dim myRange as Range

myRange = yourContantRangeDefinedHere

    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    for each cell in myRange
        'If the the cell in the next column to the right isn't empty AND the cell two columns over isn't empty
        if cell.offset(0, 1).value <> "" and cell.offset(0,2).value <> "" then
            'Do all the things here
            'Assuming your example the result is 5 columns to the right of B:B
            Msgbox cell.offset(0,5).value
        end if
    next
```

If you are then trying to search another table within the criteria of the first then you can nest another for loop within the first one.  The use the in string function `INSTR` which returns an integer of where it finds your search string within a larger string, if it doesn't find it then it returns 0.

```
dim table1Cell as Range
dim table1Range as Range
dim table1Cell as Range
dim table1Range as Range

table1Range = yourContantRangeDefinedHere
table2Range = yourSecondTableRangeHere

    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    for each table1Cell in table1Range

        ' Then we loop through the second table within the first loop
        for each table2Cell in table2Range
            'Then we will search the table1Cell value and see if it contains what is in the table2Cell value and the next column in table2

            if INSTR(1, table1Cell.value, table2Cell.value) > 0 and INSTR(1, table1Cell.value, table2Cell.offset(0,1).value) > 0 then
                'Both INSTR searches have returned a value greater than 0 so both have found matches, now you can get the value of the result column in table2 and return it to table1

                table1Cell.offset(0, 7).value = table2Cell.offset(0, 2).value
            end if
        next table2Cell
    next table1Cell
```

Comment: Hello iShaymus! Txs for your post as it solves part of my conundrum! :)
Next to be solved is, when within that loop, to take the content of the first cell in the loop and search for it in the column "B", then, when found, search whether the word in the next search column is ALSO found in the column B, then if found, and if there is a 3rd column, then check that it is ALSO found - and if so, then read the entry in the column after and copy the results...
I have added a spreadsheet exemple to try and clarify what am looking to achieve :)

Comment: I've updated my original answer.  Please understand that SO is not a code writing service, you should be attempting to write this yourself and then asking for help when you get stuck.  If this answers your question then please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Hello iShaymus!
Totally understood - tried to write that bit of code but my VBA skills are not yet good enough... Wrote to date code to manage the content / classify automatically the content of the cells, but ONLY using single testing (using the function I first mentioned in my statement) :)
Not yet up to looping and multiple search : spent 2 days last week trying to sort it out on my own, no luck - and didn't want to embarass myself displaying code that anyone experienced would have laughed at! :)

Comment: So - MANY THANKS for sorting this one out : will have a go at it and use it to understand looping / searching! Many thanks again...

Comment: Please mark the question as answered to help others in future find an answer.

Comment: Hello @iShaymus - apologies : tried to find the way to do it but couldn't... Will look better next time! Also - I assume that you did mark it as answered now, or do I still need to do it and - if so - where from? Txs. G.